# Clojure: Run map on a single value over a list of functions

Tags: function, dictionary, vector, clojure

Say I have 2 functions add1 & sub1, as defined below. From these functions I create a vector funclist.

```
(defn add1
  [x]
  (+ x 1))

(defn sub1
  [x]
  (- x 1))

(def funclist (vec '(add1 sub1)))
```

Suppose now on this list of functions, I want to run a map as below

```
(map #(% 3) funclist)
```

This gives me

```
=> (nil nil)
```

I was expecting `(4 2)...`. What am I doing wrong?

I am a complete Clojure noob... just FYI

-Abe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You turned your functions into symbols w/ the `'`.

```
(map #(type %) funclist) ;; => (clojure.lang.Symbol clojure.lang.Symbol)
```

Yet, symbols are functions too.  They can be used to look-up like `get`.
Hence the `nil` results:

```
('inc 42)
; → nil
```

Change

```
(def funclist (vec '(add1 sub1)))
```

to

```
(def funclist (vector add1 sub1)) ;; or [add1 sub1]
```

And it will work.

```
(map #(% 3) funclist) ;;=> (4 2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron. It'll go a long way in helping me wrap my head around Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish something similar with the built-in function [juxt](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt):

```clj
    (let [all-fns (juxt inc dec)]

      ;=>  (all-fns 42) => [43 41]
```

One caution:  `juxt` is somewhat obscure and a simpler approach may be better for most problems (and easier for future readers to understand).